# Liferay Portlet: how to make ajax call to serveResource Method with Parameter

Tags: java, jquery, tomcat, liferay, portlet

I have a specific problem to implement a new feature in existing code. I can't figure out how this works.
It is code from a liferay portlet to do a search query. I have a jsp file, an ajax call and a java class extending MVCPortlet. The query is a form with an input field and a submit button. I want to implement a new button with different search behavior, so the java class has to know what button is pressed. But far as I see, there is no way to implement this in a simple way, because the code examples I find in the web are different from my example. Maybe i'm just blind.

So here is the code i mentioned:

```
<div class="${baseCl}" tabindex="-1">
    <form data-dojo-attach-point="searchform" method="post">
        <input class="${baseCl}-input" name="search" data-dojo-attach-point="search" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="${searchInputValue}"/>
        <span class="${baseCl}-searchbutton"><input type="submit" data-dojo-attach-point="searchbutton" name="simpleSearchButton" value="${searchSubmitText}"/></span>
        <span class="${baseCl}-searchbutton"><input type="submit" data-dojo-attach-point="searchbutton" name="titleSearchButton" value="${searchTitleSubmitText}"/></span>
    </form>
    <div class="${baseCl}-searchresults no-display" data-dojo-attach-point="searchresults" tabindex="-1"></div>
</div>
```

This is the form. You can see I added a new button called `titleSearchButton`

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="liferay-portlet" uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletSession" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<liferay-portlet:actionURL var="searchAction" name="search" />
<portlet:resourceURL var="searchAJAXURL" />


<div data-dojo-type="simpleSearch" data-dojo-props="searchAction:'<%=searchAction %>',
                                                        searchURL:'<%=searchAJAXURL %>',
                                                        searchSubmitText:'<liferay-ui:message key="simple.search.submit.button" />',
                                                        searchTitleSubmitText:'<liferay-ui:message key="simple.search.submit.button.title" />',
                                                        searchStandartInputValue:'<liferay-ui:message key="simple.search.input.value" />',
                                                        searchInputValue:'<liferay-ui:message key="simple.search.input.value" />'
                                                        ">
</div>
```

This one is the .jsp file

```
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response)
            throws PortletException, IOException {


           Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();

            while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {

                String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();
                log.info("name = " + paramName);

                String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
                for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
                    String paramValue = paramValues[i];
                    log.info("value = " + paramValue);
                }
            }

....

}
```

And this one is just a snippet from the Code from the Java Class that is expanding MVCPortlet. There I try to read all parameters, which are send with the request Object, but the printout is a little different from what I expected:

```
name = count
value = 5
name = start
value = 0
name = searchString
value = test
name = facets
value = {}
name = method
value = simplesearch
```

So there are many parameters from which i don't know where the class gets these. The searchString from the input form is there, but in need the pressed button information as well. Any idea how to get it or to look up where these parameters are passed to this method?

The problem from other examples from the web is: there are on onclick javascript functions for the buttons. there ist no jQuery ajax or aui-io-request implementation in the code (in all portlets from this project), where the other parameters than searchString are somehow defined.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Liferay allows you pass parameters in AJAX Calls

Try making two resource URL's

`<liferay-portlet:resourceURL var="buttonClickURLA">
    <portlet:param name="<%=Constants.CMD %>" value="buttonA"/>
</liferay-portlet:resourceURL>`

`<liferay-portlet:resourceURL var="buttonClickURLB">
    <portlet:param name="<%=Constants.CMD %>" value="buttonB"/>
</liferay-portlet:resourceURL>`

pass this two URL to the corresponding two buttons  and in action class read the cmd and you can come to know which button is clicked and perform action based on the cmd value

```
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest,
            ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws IOException,
            PortletException {

        String cmd = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest,"cmd");
        if(cmd.equals("buttonA")) {
            // perform your action
        }
        if(cmd.equals("buttonB")) {
            // perform action B
        }
    }
I hope this solve your problem please let me know If you require help
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/parser", "simpleSearch", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(parser){
        parser.parse();
    });
</script>
```

where the dojo parser is run which runs the ajax calls..and add to the ajax request your data, also change ajaxURL and Action for your search